# Expected declaration specifiers or '…' before '<' token?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

This is my code that gives following error on compilation: Expected declaration specifiers or '…' before '<' token
line # 5

//Code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main(int argc, <span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">char</span> *argv[])// line 5
    {
        char *ptr;
        if(argc < 3)
        {
            printf("Usage: %s <<span id="IL_AD2" class="IL_AD">environment variable</span>> <target program name>\n", argv[0]);
            <span id="IL_AD3" class="IL_AD">exit</span>(0);
        }
        ptr = getenv(argv[1]); /* get env var location */
        ptr += (strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(argv[2]))*2; /* adjust for program name */
        printf("%s will be at %p\n", argv[1], ptr);
    }
```

Comment: Whats the HTML supposed to do in the C code?

Comment: So, you tried to copy and paste from a web page?

Comment: Strip the `<span>`s from the code, and you'll fix all your issues. ;-)

Comment: Oh, and also, please, if you're going to copy/paste code, please don't just copy it and assume it'll work unconditionally. Make sure you verify that 1. you copied it correctly, and 2. it actually does what you want it to do.

Comment: @jxh
yes I copied it from web

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are mixing two completely different languages. `HTML` and `C` have nothing to do with each other, see that they are even for different platforms.

Remove all `HTML` tags from your code and you will see that the error disappears.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr;
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s environment variable\n", argv[0]);
    }
    ptr = getenv(argv[1]); /* get env var location */
    ptr += (strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(argv[2]))*2; /* adjust for program name */
    printf("%s will be at %p\n", argv[1], ptr);
}
```

I do not know for what reason you do this, but either way it's not possible.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed

Comment: @mwaqaryb click on the gray check